# How could I see the messages being sent out by HttpClient in Angular

Tags: angular

My code posts an http message. I want to print in console to see what is being sent. How could I do this?

```
constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }
...

public createUser(user:User):any{
    console.log('contacting server at '+this.API_URL +this.ADD_USER_URL +" with user data ",user);
    /*http.post returns an observable. The caller's code should subscribe to this observable */
    return this.http.post(this.API_URL +this.ADD_USER_URL,user)
      .map(response => { //handler if post's Observable is successful. map creates new User and returns Observable<User>.
        console.log('response from backend service',response);
        //return new User(response); //the constructor of User allows passing an object.
        /*when the observable of http.post returns (produces) data (the response), the map function prints a message and returns that response*/
        return response;
      })
      .catch(this.handleError); //error handler if Observable fails
  }
```

Comment: Open your dev tools, go to the network tab, find your request, everything is there, without you having to add anything to your code. That said, you're already doing it, so I'm not sure what you're asking.

Comment: you need to subscribe to `createUser()` to make the POST execute

Comment: I dont see the HTTP requests in networks tab. At the moment, I am printing my application level values (api, user etc.) I want to see the HTTP headers. My issue is that server is returning `403 Forbidden` in some cases (related to `csrf`). I'll like to look at the HTTP headers in the request to check what is being sent in the request headers.

Comment: My issue is not subscription. My code works. I just want to find a way to check HTTP headers.

Comment: If the request is sent, then it's visible in the network tab, unless you have configured it to, for example, hide the XHR requests.

Comment: many thanks. You are correct. I must have not been looking correctly previously. Happy to accept your solution as an answer though I am not sure if I should edit the question as your answer doesn't say how to print the http request from Angular perspective.

Comment: @JB Nizet - you may provide your first comment as an answer. I'll accept it.